# Could not scan for classes inside / IlluminateQueueClosure.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Whenever I'm trying to `composer update` or delete vendor directory + `composer install` I am getting this error message:

```
 [RuntimeException]
      Could not scan for classes inside "C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\NetBeansProje
      cts\projectname\trunk\newproject\vendor/symfony/finder/Symfony/Component/Find
      er/src/Illuminate/Queue/IlluminateQueueClosure.php" which does not appear t
      o be a file nor a folder
```

Well, actually I dont have this file in my project at all. Inside of `/Finder` directory there is no `/src`. Could someone advice me on what to do now please?

I am pretty much beginning programmer so it honestly sounds to me like magic.
I work on a bigger project, they just told me to update my project and composer, but the composer update gives me this error.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug with older version of composer ...
Try to update composer using this command:

```
composer self-update
```

Then delete the "composer.lock" file in your root project folder directory and clear your composer cache by running:

```
composer clear-cache
```

Then re-run:

```
composer install
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove Vendor folder from your laravel project and run composer install again.

Comment: Not a fix at all. This is just hiding the problem.

Comment: The issue in my case was having vendor folder within the git. I removed it form the git by adding `/vendor` to `.gitignore` that resolved my issue.