# Laravel composer install doesn't work properly

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I do `composer install` for laravel, the files are being downloaded it seems and for a sec, I can see the file/directory under vendor directory. But then immediately it clears out the directory as if nothing happened. What could be the reason?

All this was working until yesterday and I don't think I haven't made any changes.

The composer.json file has all the right entries and tried deleting composer.lock file along with cache-clear, still  no luck.

Once the `composer install` finishes, it gives the error below:

`[RuntimeException]

  Could not scan for classes inside "/home/apps/coreengine/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/IlluminateQueueClosure.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder`

But this is because, there is nothing under vendor dir.

--Edit

This question is not a duplicate of the question: [Could not scan for classes inside / IlluminateQueueClosure.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630965)

I do not have anything under the vendor directory, its not the case with the previous question, also that question doesn't have any accepted answers.

Comment: What exactly is the command you're running? `composer install`? Is there any error in the terminal?

Comment: Yes `composer install` Yes in the end when generating the auto load files it shows it can't find the file. Well, thats because vendor dir is empty. Have added the error to the question.

Comment: Try removing `vendor` folder and install packages again

Comment: Yep, did that, no luck.

Comment: Or try updating the composer itself. `composer self-update`

Comment: Try running **composer dump-autoload**  and then do **composer update** or **composer install**

Comment: Errors tell us much about what we should look for: if you had look for `Illuminate/Queue/IlluminateQueueClosure.php` you would have find this answer, which i think solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630965/could-not-scan-for-classes-inside-illuminatequeueclosure-php

Comment: try providing the sudo permission for the composer install

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not scan for classes inside / IlluminateQueueClosure.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630965/could-not-scan-for-classes-inside-illuminatequeueclosure-php)

Comment: @Erubiel the vendor directory is empty, so how can check the contents of something which is presumably should be under vendor directoy?

Answer (score 0):

AS @Ragupathi said, update composer first with:

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: It says, you are already using composer version 1.7.2 (stable channel). And nothing changed. The issue still persists

Comment: Did you do the rest of the steps in the answer i provided in the comments for the question?

Comment: Yes, did that, that didn't change anything, it still creates and then immediately deletes the directories of the packages under vendor dir.

Comment: In the steps provided, theres this "hidden step" of deleting lock file before running clear cache, you did it? i mean is not listed as the others steps, rather in the comments...

Comment: I came across that somewhere else, and did that already. But just now noticed that, when I do composer clear-cache, it shows, `Cache directory does not exist (cache-vcs-dir): `

Comment: I think that is not an error, but a notification that the cache clearing was successful

Comment: It shows `All caches cleared.` so I think the cache was cleared successfully.